# Recursive function (maze solver) - can't find a bug;(((

Tags: javascript, recursion, maze

I am studying javascript and all is pretty easy to me except for some things like recursive functions. I do understand the way they work but while working with an example, I realized I can't capture the bug that prevents it from functioning...

I have an array (map) below (0 is a closed cell, 1 means path is open) and the recursive function I am trying to use to "find" path out of this "maze" by going from its top left cell to the bottom-right one.. Basically just make the function to "find" this path of 1s. But it fails;(

```
var map = [
        [1,1,0,0],
        [0,1,1,0],
        [0,0,1,0],
        [0,0,1,1]
    ]

function findpath(x,y) {
    if (x<0 || x>3 || y<0 || y>3) return false; //if it is outside of map
    if (x==3 && y==3) return true; // if it is the goal (exit point)
    if (map[y][x]==0) return false; //it is not open
    map[y][x]=9; //here marking x,y position as part of solution path outlined by "9"
    if (findpath(x,y-1) == true) return true;
    if (findpath(x+1,y) == true) return true;
    if (findpath(x,y+1) == true) return true;
    if (findpath(x-1,y) == true) return true;
    map[y][x]=8; //unmark x,y as part of solution path outlined by "8"
    return false;
    };
findpath(0,0);
```

Comment: ...How exactly does it fail? An error message or description of 'wrong' behavior would be quite useful.

Comment: Your code includes adding "markers", but nothing ever *checks* for the markers.

Comment: Your code is marking `map[0][1]` and `map[1][1]` as `9`s, over and over again, because `9` doesn't actually mean anything in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer:

Its locking in a loop because the order of the checks.

Start from 0:0 then try 0:1. Then from 0:1 --"Ummm... 0:0 looks promising. Let's go there". So go back to 0:0... so it locks...
Try leaving backtracking last :

```
if(findpath(x+1,y)) return true;    
if(findpath(x,y+1)) return true;    
if(findpath(x,y-1)) return true;
if(findpath(x-1,y)) return true;
```

This get you out of the lock just by swapping the issue around. If you start from 3:3 trying to reach 0:0 you'll be locked again.
Whats missing its a way to mark visited squares.

I think you are trying to implement an [a* algorithm](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)

UPDATE:

Here is your idea working. Just added the backtracking checks you almost implemented.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var map = [
            [1,1,0,0],
            [0,1,1,0],
            [1,1,1,0],
            [1,0,1,1]
        ]
        
    var goalx = 0;
    var goaly = 3;
    
    console.log();
    
    function findpath(x,y) {
        
        
        // illegal move check
        if (x < 0 || x > (map[0].length -1) || y < 0 || y > (map.length - 1)) return false; //if it is outside of map
        if (map[y][x]==0) return false; //it is not open
        
        // end move check
        if (x== goalx && y== goaly){
            console.log('Reached goal at: ' + x + ':' + y);
            return true; // if it is the goal (exit point)
        }
        
        if(map[y][x] == 9 || map[y][x] == 8)
            return false;
        
        console.log('Im here at: ' + x + ':' + y);
        
        map[y][x]=9; //here marking x,y position as part of solution path outlined by "9"
        
        if(findpath(x+1,y)) 
            return true;    
        if(findpath(x,y+1)) 
            return true;    
        if(findpath(x,y-1))
            return true;
        if(findpath(x-1,y)) 
            return true;                    
        
        map[y][x]=8; //unmark x,y as part of solution path outlined by "8"
        
        return false;
    };
    
    findpath(3, 3);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ohhh yes I think I was too stressed to think logically and present my case in full and proper details. Sorry for that. And huge applause for helping me out. Once at my pc I will provide my comments. But I see the main issue thanks to you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The description of "it fails" is rarely, if ever, a **useful** error report.

In order for someone to help you, they need much more detail than that.

In this case, the import details came out of the JavaScript error console.  You should *always* include any error messages in your question.

However, since your code was quite short I was able to cut-and-paste it into my console where I got the message:

> `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

This means that your function is recursing too deeply.  You either

- Have bad logic in your puzzle and you are recursing into the same values over and over again
- The puzzle is too complicated and you can't solve it recursively like that.

You need to add `console.log` statements and observe what the code is doing and see why it is going so deep.

If it is a logic error, fix the logic error. (Hint: I'm pretty sure it is -- you never mark on the map where you've *been*  so it freely goes back and forth and back and forth over the same spot).

If it isn't, then you need to use some more advanced trick to work around the recursion, such as using a generator function and storing  the changes you do in the map separately.

Comment: Hey Jeremy - you are right. I will make sure I present my cases in a clearere way. And thanks for the tip I will use console.log actively now:)